# How to make page with Highcharts valid HTML5?

Tags: html, highcharts, w3c-validation

I'm trying to have my page containing Highcharts.js validated against http://validator.w3.org/

But it seems like the validator doesn't like SVG being embedded into my document after the graph is loaded (or whatever actually is being done), and gives me errors like these:

> "Attribute title not allowed on element g at this point."
>
> "Attribute zindex not allowed on element path at this point."

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: What page? Can we have some code?

Comment: Just tested with simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/916/show/ - works fine.

Comment: I'm using the "Direct input" version of the validator. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I don't think so. Without live demo we won't be able fix that in Highcharts (of course if it's Highcharts bug, not validator).